# How to add tooltip in Echarts to Radar indicator

Tags: javascript, charts, data-visualization, tooltip, echarts

I am trying to add tooltips to the Radar indicator elements. So far I tried `tooltip:{show:true, trigger: "item", value:"tooltipText"}` in the indicator element but no luck :(, can be seen below in the code. For example if I hover on top of "销售（Sales)" it should show a tooltip with "tooltipText".

Running code example: https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=radar

```
option = {
    title: {
        text: '基础雷达图'
    },
    legend: {
        data: ['预算分配（Allocated Budget）', '实际开销（Actual Spending）']
    },
    tooltip: {
        trigger: 'item'
    },
    radar: {
        // shape: 'circle',
        indicator: [
            { name: '销售（Sales）', max: 6500, tooltip:{show:true, trigger: "item", value:"tooltipText"}},
            { name: '管理（Administration）', max: 16000, tooltip:{show:true, trigger: "item", value:"tooltipText"}},
            { name: '信息技术（Information Technology）', max: 30000, tooltip:{show:true, trigger: "item", value:"tooltipText"}}
        ]
    },
    series: [{
        name: '预算 vs 开销（Budget vs spending）',
        type: 'radar',
        data: [
            {
                value: [4200, 3000, 20000, 35000, 50000, 18000],
                name: '预算分配（Allocated Budget）'
            },
            {
                value: [5000, 14000, 28000, 26000, 42000, 21000],
                name: '实际开销（Actual Spending）'
            }
        ]
    }]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add "tooltip: {}" inside option. Like this, you can change the tooltip inside the series option, the same way you were doing before.

The code would look like this:

```
option = {
title: {
    text: '基础雷达图'
},
legend: {
    data: ['预算分配（Allocated Budget）', '实际开销（Actual Spending）']
},
radar: {
    // shape: 'circle',
    indicator: [
        { name: '销售（Sales）', max: 6500},
        { name: '管理（Administration）', max: 16000},
        { name: '信息技术（Information Technology）', max: 30000},
        { name: '客服（Customer Support）', max: 38000},
        { name: '研发（Development）', max: 52000},
        { name: '市场（Marketing）', max: 25000}
    ]
},
tooltip: {},
series: [{
    name: '预算 vs 开销（Budget vs spending）',
    type: 'radar',
    data: [
        {
            value: [4200, 3000, 20000, 35000, 50000, 18000],
            name: '预算分配（Allocated Budget）'
        },
        {
            value: [5000, 14000, 28000, 26000, 42000, 21000],
            name: '实际开销（Actual Spending）'
        }
    ],
    tooltip:{
       // do something here if you want
    }
}]
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the tooltip div from canvas and append it to the body worked for me.